# Referring with cleveref to a custom listing (\lstnewenvironment)

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, cleveref, code

I use cleveref's `\cref` command for referencing, and `\lstnewenvironment` to create a new listing type. My document has multiple types of listings, each of them with their own counter.

However, cleveref insists on calling all types of listings `listing`, despite my definition of a `\crefname` for the custom listing types.

**How can I refer with the correct label to a custom listing?**

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,cleveref}

% Define listing type for queries
\newcounter{query}
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{query}[1][]
{%
  \lstset{#1}%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Query}%
  \let\c@lstlisting=\c@query%
  \let\thelstlisting=\thequery%
}
{}
\makeatother

% Set up reference label
\crefname{query}{query}{queries}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:MyListing,caption=My listing]
  # Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{query}[label=qry:MyQuery,caption=My query]
  SELECT * FROM MyTable;
\end{query}

Reference to \cref{lst:MyListing} and \cref{qry:MyQuery}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So the key to making this work is changing that? How would we go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can coerce `listings` into using the right counter instead of the default `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,listings,cleveref}

% Define listing type for queries
\newcounter{query}
\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{query}[1][]
 {%
  % make \lst@MakeCaption use query instead of lstlisting
  \patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{{lstlisting}}{{query}}{}{}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,#1}%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Query}%
  \let\thelstlisting=\thequery
 }
 {}
\makeatother

% Set up reference label
\crefname{query}{query}{queries}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:MyListing,caption=My listing]
  # Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{query}[label=qry:MyQuery,caption=My query]
  SELECT * FROM MyTable;
\end{query}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:MyListing2,caption=My listing]
  # Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{query}[label=qry:MyQuery2,caption=My query]
  SELECT * FROM MyTable;
\end{query}

Reference to \cref{lst:MyListing} and \cref{qry:MyQuery}.

Reference to \cref{lst:MyListing2} and \cref{qry:MyQuery2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Fix for cooperation with `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,listings,hyperref,bookmark,cleveref}

% Define listing type for queries
\newcounter{query}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{{lstlisting}}{{\verborgh@counter}}{}{}%
\def\verborgh@counter{lstlisting}
\def\verborgh@prefix{L}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\theHlstnumber}{\thelstnumber}{\verborgh@prefix\thelstnumber}{}{}%
}

\lstnewenvironment{query}[1][]
 {%
  % make \lst@MakeCaption use query instead of lstlisting
  \def\verborgh@counter{query}%
  \def\verborgh@prefix{Q}%
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,#1}%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Query}%
 }
 {}
\makeatother

% Set up reference label
\crefname{query}{query}{queries}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:MyListing,caption=My listing]
  # Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{query}[label=qry:MyQuery,caption=My query]
  SELECT * FROM MyTable;
\end{query}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:MyListing2,caption=My listing]
  # Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{query}[label=qry:MyQuery2,caption=My query]
  SELECT * FROM MyTable;
\end{query}

Reference to \cref{lst:MyListing} and \cref{qry:MyQuery}.

Reference to \cref{lst:MyListing2} and \cref{qry:MyQuery2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg, this works great for the MWE I had provided. Unfortunately, it fails in my actual document, because I also use the `hyperref` package (which I load before `cleveref`). Could you perhaps also indicate how it could work in this situation?

Comment: @RubenVerborgh The fix for cooperation with `hyperref` is online.

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm!